# Apach cxf soap wsdl without complexType

Tags: java, spring, soap, jaxb, cxf

I create a soap web service using apache cxf ,whenI publish my web service I get a WSDL without complex Type section , this's my code :

My Interafce :

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://v4.ws.provider.acp.com/", name = "IGetAuthorizationDetails")
public interface IGetAuthorizationDetailsWebService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "getAuthorizationDetailsV4")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "getAuthorization_V4", targetNamespace = "http://request.message.provider.acp.com/", className = "ws.model.request.GetAuthorizationDetailsV4")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "getAuthorizationDetails_V4Response", targetNamespace = "http://response.message.provider.acp.com/", className = "ws.model.response.GetAuthorizationDetails4Response")
    @WebResult(name = "GetAuthorizationDetailsV4Rs", targetNamespace = "")
    public GetAuthorizationDetailsV4Rs getAuthorizationDetails4(

            @WebParam(name = "GetAuthorizationDetailsV4Rq", targetNamespace = "")
            @Valid GetAuthorizationDetailsV4Rq request
    ) throws TechnicalException;
}
```

My configuration :

```
  @Bean
    public ISearchAuthorizationWebServicePort getISearchAuthorizationWebServicePort(){
        return new ISearchAuthorizationWebServicePort();
    }

@Bean
    public Endpoint getIGetAuthorizationDetailsEndpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus,  getIGetAuthorizationDetailsWebServicePort());
        endpoint.publish("/GetAuthorizationDetailsTest/V4");

        return endpoint;
    }
```

My request object :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "GetAuthorizationDetailsV4Rq", namespace = "http://request.message.provider.acp.com/", propOrder = {
        "referenceNumber",
})
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class GetAuthorizationDetailsV4Rq extends AbstractMessageV4Rq {

    @XmlElement(name = "referenceNumber")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Za-z0-9]*$", message = "ReferenceNumber must contains only alphanumeric characters")
 private String referenceNumber ;
   

}
```

And this's the WSDL generated :

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.api.controller.ws/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:ns1="http://v4.ws.provider.acp.com/" name="IGetAuthorizationDetailsWebServicePortService" targetNamespace="http://ws.api.controller.ws.pwc/">
<wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8082/home/GetAuthorizationDetails/V4?wsdl=IGetAuthorizationDetails.wsdl" namespace="http://v4.ws.provider.acp.com/"> </wsdl:import>
<wsdl:binding name="IGetAuthorizationDetailsWebServicePortServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:IGetAuthorizationDetails">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="getAuthorizationDetailsV4">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="getAuthorizationDetailsV4">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="getAuthorizationDetailsV4Response">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="TechnicalException">
<soap:fault name="TechnicalException" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="IGetAuthorizationDetailsWebServicePortService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:IGetAuthorizationDetailsWebServicePortServiceSoapBinding" name="IGetAuthorizationDetailsWebServicePortPort">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8082/home/GetAuthorizationDetails/V4"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Why In my generated WSDL i can't find my request attributes like "referenceNumber"

Comment: Where id you define the `referenceNumber` field? Is it a typo? It seems not included in `GetAuthorizationDetailsV4Rq`.

Comment: I update my code I added the field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the imported WSDL to see if the request object is defined there. Look at this line in your WSDL:

```
<wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8082/home/GetAuthorizationDetails/V4?wsdl=IGetAuthorizationDetails.wsdl" namespace="http://v4.ws.provider.acp.com/"> </wsdl:import>
```

If you open `http://localhost:8082/home/GetAuthorizationDetails/V4?wsdl=IGetAuthorizationDetails.wsdl` in your browser what does it contain? Is your type and reference number in there?

Finally, I would try to use only one XML namespace in defining the web service and all its component elements. Right now you have two namespaces from what I see:

```
http://request.message.provider.acp.com/
http://v4.ws.provider.acp.com/
```

... and CXF is creating the WSDL in two parts. Using one namespace should give you one complete WSDL with no imports and just one URL to use. See also: [CXF autogenerates WSDL imports itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011661/cxf-autogenerates-wsdl-imports-itself)

Comment: when I used your url my wsdl contains all the objects type ! how i can set this url as default url in the catalogue wsdl by default i get this url http://localhost:8082/home/GetAuthorizationDetails/V4?wsdl

Comment: @e2rabi: your default URL should work, even if it includes parts from some place else. So the WSDL generated above is fine. If you want just one URL see my updated answer.